# OAuth1 in Clojure

Tags: rest, oauth, clojure

I'm trying to integrate with an API (Context.IO) using Clojure. Context.IO uses OAuth 1, which requires to inform consumer key and consumer secret credentials to integrate with.

I've manage to work with Context.IO with Node.JS in the past, using request library (https://github.com/request/request). It turn out to be quite simple, just filled consumer_key and consumer_secret in an object and passed it in oauth parameter in the request.

```
var oauth   = 
{
  consumer_key: 'dsfdfssdf',
  consumer_secret: 'dasfsafdsf'
};

request.post( { url:url, oauth:oauth } )
```

Now I'm trying to accomplish the same using clj-oauth https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth, but I'm kinda lost, because it requires too different parameters (for more complex use cases I guess), and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to do the simple.

To add more information, Context IO uses OAuth only for API Authentication, not user Authorization. So it doesn't require tokens to be informed, neither provides one. It only requires the consumer key and signature (the same described here:  dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures).

Can someone give an example similar to what I accomplished in Node using Clojure or clj-oauth (or any other library)? I haven't found a way to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: I am using that library right now.  If you follow the readme, it works...

Comment: Hi Red Deck, thanks for the response. For instance the make-consumer function accepts 3 URLs as parameters, which I don't have. I have available only consumer key, secret and the method (hmac-sha1).

Comment: well generally the urls follow the same pattern.  For example this worked for me for Goodreads      "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token"
"https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token"
"https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize"

Comment: Hi Red Deck, I've studied the problem further and I'm writing to give more details about it. OAuth in the Context IO scenario is just used for API authentication not user authorization. So when making a request the token is not informed at all. The only parameters informed are the consumer key and a signature (which is a hash o the request). The signature is as described here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures. So it seems it would make no sense to inform the extra parameters, and Context doesn't supply those.  So I still don't know how to use the library :(

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I signed up for context io to give this a go.  First, in leiningen I set up

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [clj-oauth "1.5.2"]
                 [clj-http "1.1.2"]]
```

as my dependencies.  There are two examples below.  One calls a url without any parameters, the other calls the same url, but with parameters.

```
(ns scratch.core
  (:require [oauth.client :as oauth]
            [clj-http.client :as http]))

(def okey "key")

(def osecret "secret")

(def consumer (oauth/make-consumer okey
                                   osecret
                                   nil
                                   nil
                                   nil
                                   :hmac-sha1))

(defn test-get []
  (let [credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                       nil
                                       nil
                                       :GET
                                       "https://api.context.io/lite/users")]
    (http/get "https://api.context.io/lite/users" {:query-params credentials})))

(defn test-get-params []
  (let [params {:email "blah@blah.com"}
        credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                       nil
                                       nil
                                       :GET
                                       "https://api.context.io/lite/users"
                                       params)]
    (http/get "https://api.context.io/lite/users" {:query-params (merge credentials params)})))
```

Comment: I was trying to use this answer to configure my OAuth access to the Goodreads API to get a member's list of friends in XML but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have also posted a question on stackoverflow with what I have so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920728/configuring-oauth-with-goodreads-in-clojure Any help would be much appreciated.