# How to configure OAuth with Goodreads in Clojure

Tags: xml, api, oauth, clojure, compojure

I am trying to configure OAuth to use it to access data from the Goodreads API using Clojure and Compojure framework. I basically want to get a list of firends that a Goodreads member has. I should mention that I am new to Clojure and completely new to OAuth and in general to API authentication so I would really appreciate it if it could be explained as simply as possible.

I tried to find the answer online but was unable to find one that would help me as many sites deal with specific OAuth API configurations and those seem to differ widely from API to API in terms of configuring access with OAuth. Furthermore not many of them use Clojure to explain OAuth API configuration and those that do differ too much in terms of what is required for that specific API access. The Goodreads API page was not really helpful either. Finally I found the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107730/oauth1-in-clojure) and tried to use it as a template to configure my OAuth access to the Goodreads API. It uses the [clj-oauth](https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth) which I tried to use in combination with the answer to the above mentioned question since simply replacing the data from the answer to that question with Goodreads addresses didn't work. This is what I have now but it just returns a 401 error and I have no idea what I am doing wrong:

```
(def okey "goodreads-key")

(def osecret "goodreads-secret")

(def consumer (oauth/make-consumer okey
                                   osecret
                                   "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token"
                                   "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token"
                                   "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize"
                                   :hmac-sha1))

(def request-token (oauth/request-token consumer nil))

(oauth/user-approval-uri consumer 
                         (:oauth_token request-token))

(def access-token-response (oauth/access-token consumer 
                                               request-token
                                               nil))

(defn test-get []
  (let [credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                       (:oauth_token access-token-response)
                                       (:oauth_token_secret access-token-response)
                                       :GET
                                       "https://www.goodreads.com/friend/user/user-id-number?format=xml")]
    (http/get "https://www.goodreads.com/friend/user/user-id-number?format=xml" {:query-params credentials})))
```

The clj-oauth says in the Client Example that there should be a callback-uri in the request-token and a verifier in the access-token-response, but since I am not familiar with OAuth I put nil there.

The answer to the above question doesn't use the following lines from my code:

```
(def request-token (oauth/request-token consumer nil))

(oauth/user-approval-uri consumer 
                         (:oauth_token request-token))

(def access-token-response (oauth/access-token consumer 
                                               request-token
                                               nil))
```

And subsequently doesn't use the "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token"
                                   "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token"
                                   "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize" addresses in the `consumer` nor does it use (:oauth_token access-token-response)
                                       (:oauth_token_secret access-token-response) in `test-get`, but instead replaces those values with `nil`, but since it didn't work I tried to combine it with the example mentioned on clj-oauth github page mentioned above, but it still doesn't work.

I am simply trying to get a XML response of a member's list of friends from the Goodreads API and any help configuring this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Goodreads definitely needs a request/access token.  The callback uri for goodreads is set on goodreads itself, so it doesn't matter what you pass in for that.  I've actually worked with the goodreads api in clojure before, i'll take a stab at this later today.

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't figured this out so I really look forward to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so my project.clj looks like this:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [clj-oauth "1.5.2"]
                 [clj-http "1.1.2"]]
```

Sample code:

```
(ns scratch.core
  (:require [oauth.client :as oauth]
            [clj-http.client :as http]))

(def consumer-key "your_key")
(def consumer-secret "your_secret")

;Step 1: Create an oath consumer object
(def consumer (oauth/make-consumer consumer-key
                                   consumer-secret
                                   "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token"
                                   "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token"
                                   "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize"
                                   :hmac-sha1))
;Step 2: Create a request token.  These can only be used once.  They usually expire as well.
(def request-token (oauth/request-token consumer nil))

;Step 3:  Have the goodreads user approve your application.  They can approve your application by visting the url
; produced by the call below.
(oauth/user-approval-uri consumer
                         (:oauth_token request-token))

;Step 4:  Once the goodreads user has approved your application, you can exchange the request token for an access token.
;An access token is per-user.  Goodreads in particular will only issue 1 per user, so don not lose this access token.
(def access-token-response (oauth/access-token consumer
                                               request-token
                                               nil))

;Step 5: Get the user id of the user who approved your application.
;you can parse the user id out from this.  I used clojure.zip, clojure.data.zip.xml, and clojure.data.xml to parse this out.
(defn get-user-id []
  (let [url "https://www.goodreads.com/api/auth_user"
        credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                       (:oauth_token access-token-response)
                                       (:oauth_token_secret access-token-response)
                                       :GET
                                       url)]
    (http/get url {:query-params credentials})))

(get-user-id)

;Step 6: Get the friends of the user.
(defn get-friends [user-id]
  (let [url (str "https://www.goodreads.com/friend/user/" user-id)
        params {:format "xml"}
        credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                       (:oauth_token access-token-response)
                                       (:oauth_token_secret access-token-response)
                                       :GET
                                       url
                                       params)]
    (http/get url {:query-params (merge credentials params)})))

(get-friends <a user id>)
```

EDIT:

Ok I reran the exact code above (redacted api keys and user id) and am 100% sure it works.  I would highly recommend creating a throwaway Goodreads account to test with.

Here is a [screenshot of a successful request](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1wv0lvnpey5g1q/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-07%20at%208.09.44%20PM.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I try to use this code with my api key and consumer-secret and my user id I get a 401 error. Like so: clj-http: status 401 {:orig-content-encoding "gzip", :trace-redirects ["https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token"], :request-time 476, :status 401, :headers {"Server" "Server", "Content-Type" "text/html; charset=utf-8", "X-Content-Type-Options" "nosniff", "Content-Length" "487", "X-Runtime" "0.041770", "X-Frame-Options" "SAMEORIGIN", "WWW-Authenticate" "OAuth realm=\"http://www.goodreads.com\"", "Status" "401 Unauthorized".

Comment: Btw, I got the token and secret by running request-token and then going to the address "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=a_token" with my token instead of a_token in the address. I approved my app there. Yet when I run the function (get-friends my-user-id) with my user id I still get the "401 Unauthorized" message and I don't know why that is. Am I missing a step? Did I do something worng here? Sorry if these questions seem like newbie questions, but I am completely new to OAuth and am new to Clojure as well.

Comment: I ran this code and it works, so I don't really know what to say.  The address you visit should be the one generated by the oauth/user-approval-uri call.

Comment: When I run (oauth/user-approval-uri consumer (:oauth_token request-token)) I get an address back. Whenever I visit that address it says the app has already been approved. Yet, when I try to run the entire code with my user id supplied as a string to the (get-friends) function I get that 401 error saying that it's unauthorized. I ran the code several times and still I get the same answer. I copied the first response from the request-token and even hard coded in the oauth-token and oauth-token-secret but it still doesn't work. Have I messed something up by requesting the token more than once?

Comment: Btw, all I changed in your code the first time I ran it was the consumer key and consumer secret and added in my own and where the get-friends function is called I added my own user id. Then I ran the entire code and got the 401. After that I ran just the request-token and it returned a map of oauth-token and oauth-token-secret values to me which I copied and saved. I then authorized it. After trying to run the code several times I then tried to hard-code in the values for oauth-token and oauth-token secret in get-user-id and get-friends functions but still got the same 401 Unauthorized error.

Comment: If it's of any help it says at the end of the 401 error  I get in my REPL compiling:(oauthcon.clj:22:28) and for me line 22 is (def access-token-response...

Comment: Ok I re-ran the code and am 100% sure it works.  You should create a new throwaway goodreads user to test this against.  Additionally, make sure you are using the same versions of the libraries I am using.

Comment: Ok, I finally got it work. The problem was in access-token-response. So instead I ran the code that was in access-token-response on its own (without calling access-token-response, just the code in it) and got an access token. I copied the answer and inserted it instead of access-token-response calls in functions (get-user-id) and (get-friends <user id>) and that produced a successful response. I still don't know why your answer didn't work with me as I see no reason why it shouldn't but with this slight modification it works. Thank you so much for your time and help. I really appreciate it. :)